# no attribute '_inbound_nodes' error even when using Lambda layer in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a **(28,000 x 300)** dimension matrix, let's call it **label_embedding**, which I want to do a dot product with the bottleneck layer of my model. I have created an architecture which gives a **(batch_size x 300)** at its bottleneck layer.

I am using a generator function for input. The label_embedding matrix is taken as input in the following way:

```
inp7 = Input(tensor=labels_embeddings)
```

And for the dot product I am doing the following:

```
out = Lambda(dot_)([x1, K.transpose(inp7)])
```

where x1 is the bottleneck layer and dot_ is:

```
def dot_(tensors):
    return K.dot(tensors[0], tensors[1])
```

The problem is that even though the shape of the out variable is correct, that is, **(batch_size x 28000)**, I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
P.S.: I am using tensorflow and keras

P.S.: I have been using keras layers until the out variable where I use keras backend as K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem. So all backend based functions need to be wrapped within the lambda layer. So instead of:

```
out = Lambda(dot_)([x1, K.transpose(inp7)])
```

and

```
def dot_(tensors):
    return K.dot(tensors[0], tensors[1])
```

I wrote:

```
out = Lambda(dot_)([x1, inp7])
```

and

```
def dot_(tensors):
    return K.dot(tensors[0], K.transpose(tensors[1]))
```